# I want to fetch data from facebook's profile. I am able to login but its not calling the onSuccess(). in Android studio

Tags: android, facebook

I want to fetch data of user like name, email and other details. I am able to login using facbook API. But I foound out the onSuccess() method is not executing. however it shows me log in.

```
public class SignInUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginButton fbLoginBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //intialize fb sdk
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_up);

        fbLoginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.ObiNoID_SignIn_SignUpActivity_btn_fb_login);

        // setting permission for fb accounts
        fbLoginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


        fbLoginBtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                                try {
                                    String email = object.getString("email");
                                    String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                    Toast.makeText(SignInUpActivity.this,email+birthday,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(SignInUpActivity.this, "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(SignInUpActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);// will call the call
    }


}
```

I am a begginer please help me solve the problem.

Comment: are you using default facebook login button or custom login button

Comment: String email = object.getString("email");
                                String birthday = object.getString("birthday"); comment these 2 lines and check and in toast just use onSuccess

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
private void connectToFacebook() {

        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Success");
                            String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                            System.out.println("JSON Result" + jsonresult);

                            String fbUserId = json.optString("id");
                            String fbUserFirstName = json.optString("name");
                            String fbUserEmail = json.optString("email");
                            String fbUserProfilePics = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fbUserId + "/picture?type=large";

                        }
                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                    }
                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                // Log.v("LoginActivity", "" + exception);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: He has used default LoginButton

Comment: have you tried using custom button ? and what problem your facing now?